# Android launching navigation within app

Tags: android, navigation

I am developing an Android application for children going to a bus stop. I have the navigation button in my app. When pressed, the GPS gets on and I get the latitude and longitude of the bus stop. An intent is fired, launching Google Navigation app with the values of the child's `current location` and the `lat,long` values of the bus stop. This launches Google Navigation app showing the route to the bus stop making my app go in background.

The user(child) has to exit navigation in order to view the bus stops in the app.

So what I am planning to do is make an in app navigation by launching navigation window half of the screen. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

This is official Google API for Maps. Using just several import statements and some code you can utilise maps in your app. Demos and code samples are under the link. Good luck :)